# Why FFTW libraries are not loaded by GCC on the cluster?

Tags: c, linux, cluster-computing, fftw

I am trying to execute a simple FFT using FFTW 3.3.5 over the cluster.

```
fftwf_plan plan = fftwf_plan_dft_1d(N, idata, odata, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
//--------------------Perform FFT--------------------------
fftwf_execute(plan);

//-------------------Inverse FFT--------------------------
plan = fftwf_plan_dft_1d(N, odata, odata, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftwf_execute(plan);
fftwf_destroy_plan(plan);
```

I have tried using the following commands to execute the above code.

`gcc -o fftw.out /cm/extra/apps/FFTW/3.3.5/GCC-4.9.3_MVAPICH2-2.2-GDR/lib/libfftw3.a -lm fftwCPU.c`

`gcc -o fftw.out -lfftw3 -lm fftwCPU.c -L/cm/extra/apps/FFTW/3.3.5/GCC-4.9.3_MVAPICH2-2.2-GDR/lib/`

The path is also loaded in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

GCC is able to find the path correctly but it is not linking the library. I am getting an undefined references error to all the functions of fftw.

In the above code, I have also used the fftw_ functions instead of fftwf_ functions.

More importantly, This exact code is running without any problems on my local system.

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Usually, you would put `-lfftw` after `fftwCPU.c` in the call.

Comment: `gcc -o fftw.out fftwCPU.c -L/cm/extra/apps/FFTW/3.3.5/GCC-4.9.3_MVAPICH2-2.2-GDR/lib/ -lm -lfftw3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your option order is not correct: put the `-l` options last, like so:

```
$ gcc -o fftw.out fftwCPU.c -L/cm/extra/apps/FFTW/3.3.5/GCC-4.9.3_MVAPICH2-2.2-GDR/lib/ -lfftw3 -lm
```

This is also logical; you should specify the paths before specifying which libraries to load from those paths.

From [the fine manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-l):

> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified. Thus, ‘foo.o -lz bar.o’ searches library ‘z’ after file foo.o but before bar.o. If bar.o refers to functions in ‘z’, those functions may not be loaded.